# In-App purchase not renew all subscriptions under sandbox?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, sandbox, subscription

It's been tested for several test accounts, auto renewal only works on two subscriptions when there are three in total(they were bought within one minute). I then tried to buy the missing subscription individually with a new account, its renewal work well!

Does Apple disable multiple subscriptions renewal under sandbox? if not, any idea what make this error happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're trying to renew more than 6 times per day. Sandbox doesn't work well with renews if you purchase subscriptions too often.
Best practice is testing each subscription group in a new sandbox account.
Do you really have an app with three subscription groups?

Comment: As i said in the question, I tested it with new sandbox account. And I do create three subscription groups, put all products in one group will increase the price. Selling separately, I think user can choose what they want with lower price.